# Do first pregnancies tend to deliver later than the due-date?

Tags: united-states, pregnancy, statistics

Many online resources state that it's very unlikely for a pregnancy to result in a delivery *exactly on the estimated due date*. I've seen the number of about 5%, but can't find it nor am much interested in this information specifically.

There is also a popular opinion saying that the **first pregnancy natural labor usually happens *after a due date* rather than on or before it**.

As you can tell, I am a bit skeptical about it. Could anyone point me to an official source that has the information on the distribution of terms of the natural labors in the first pregnancies?

Here's a [link to a site](https://www.livescience.com/38179-royal-baby-firstborns-late.html) that says:

> Babies don't always arrive when they're supposed to, and mothers often say firstborns tend to be late, although this conclusion is typically based on anecdotal reports
>
> He [Allen Downey] found that first babies were, indeed, slightly more likely to be born late, at 41 weeks or later, compared with other babies (second-borns, third-borns, etc.)

---

I do not know if this question is location related. But for the sake of specificity you can assume I'm asking about the United States.

Comment: Just noting that a quick search shows this to be notable.

Comment: @Oddthinking The opinion is expressed by pretty much every single mother under age 30 my wife and I have talked to. Does Skeptics.SE require a source to be "documented" in order to make the question valid? I apologize in advance if that is the case and I missed it.

Comment: @Oddthinking Also, there's plenty of stats on pregnancy duration in general case, but my question is specifically about the first pregnancies.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the comment shortly after I posted it. In general, yes, [we require the source to be documented](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to show it is notable. When I searched to find something to edit into the question, what I found was lots of people with scientific evidence about the answer, but no-one actually making the claim without evidence.

Comment: @Oddthinking please take a look at the source I added. It refers to a study conducted by Allen Downey. Will that be sufficient to make my question conform with the site rules?

Comment: I avoided adding a reference like that, because it pretty much answers your question. Anyone answering now must give *better* evidence than that.

Comment: @oddthinking yeah, and that's exactly what I'm asking for -- more precise source that shows raw data,  or study explained in details.

Comment: : Ok. Great. Look forward to seeing some answers.